# Increase the resolution of Google Earth Engine images

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth, imagery, resolution

I am trying to fetch high quality images from Google Earth Engine. I want to understand the relationship between zoom_level option in:
`Map.centerObject(image, zoom_level);`

and scale option in below code:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
      image: img,
      description:'desc'
      scale: 1,
      maxPixels:1e13,
      folder:"japan"
    });
```

I want to get a high quality image of a specific location with as high zoom as possible. I believe scale 1 (1m per pixel) is the highest resolution possible, but the image is not at all clear for human eye. How can I increase the resolution of the image that I am fetching from Google Earth Engine?

Comment: what image is it? is it an image you uploaded? what's its original resolution?

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe. It's the image from landsat8 collection. I have filtered the collection by specific dates, and filtered by point(lat,long) boundary. and then I added ` image.visualize({bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 6000, max: 20000}); ` to make it human viewable, and finally I am exporting the image.

Comment: Look at the Landsat 8 platform specs.  The panchromatic band is 15 meters, the multispectral bands are 30m, and the thermal bands are 100m.  You're not going to get 1m imagery from a 15m/30m/100m platform.

Comment: Please ask new question as Questions.

Comment: Vince deleted. But coming to this question how can I tweak scale and zoom level to increase the resolution, does changin min,max arguments in image.visualize improve the resolution?